# What does this source "IAA iii" mean? Which book?

Tags: book, mongol-empire

I've been reading a book about Genghis Khan by Frank McLynn and, going through its notes, I saw sources where I couldn't find anything about it, i.e. what publication was referred to.

I want to find this source designated as "IAA iii".

[image: Spuler, Mongolen in Iran p. 30; Minorsky, Caucasian History pp. 149-156. • 45. IAA iii pp. 272-273 • 46. JR i p. 296 • 47. IAA iii p. 288 • 48. JR i p. 297 • 49. JB ii pp. 438-439 • 50. IAA iii p. 289 • 51. Lewis, Assassins; Hodgson, Secret Order; Daftary, Ismailis • 52. Minorsky, Caucasian History p. 156 • 53. JB ii pp. 441-443 • 54. IAA iii pp. 258-259; Minorsky, Caucasian History pp. 102-103; Grousset, Empire pp. 260-261 • 55. IAA iii pp. 297-298 • 56. ibid. p. 298 • 57.]

Comment: All reference sources do abbreviations like this, even Wikipedia. You're supposed to scan back through the prior references until you find the first one, which should contain the un-abbreviated version of the name.

Comment: @T.E.D. Well, _all should_ do it like that. But sometimes they 'forget to' And then there are classics. Or theology. In both cases such 'list of abbrvs' I'd support unconditionally, always, but often miss them in books…

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is explained — as it should be — as a frequently used abbreviation, on page 559, at the start of section called "Notes":

> Abbreviations of principal primary sources used in the notes: […]
>
> IAA: Richards, D. S., ed. & trans., The Chronicle of Ibn al-Athir for the Crusading Period from Al-Kamil fi’l-Ta’rikh, Part 3: The Years 589–629/1193–1231: The Ayyubids after Saladin and the Mongol Menace (2008)

— Frank McLynn: "Genghis Khan: his conquests, his empire, his legacy", Da Capo Press: Boston, 2015. [worldcat](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/888556978)

Which would land you at:

["The Chronicle of Ibn al-Athir for the Crusading Period from al-Kamil fi'l-Ta'rikh. Part 3

The Years 589–629/1193–1231: The Ayyubids after Saladin and the Mongol Menace" — Edited By D.S. Richards](https://www.routledge.com/The-Chronicle-of-Ibn-al-Athir-for-the-Crusading-Period-from-al-Kamil-fil-Tarikh/Richards/p/book/9780754669524)

The referenced bit for this specific endnote then seems to apply to the 'chapter'/entry in that book:

> The Year 625 [1227-1228] —
> Account of dissension between Jalal al-Din and his brother